# Use a higher resolution background image in an animation render

Tags: animation, compositing-nodes, image

I have a image which has full HD resolution (1920x1080) and I want to use it as background for my animation without decreasing the resolution. My animation is in HD resolution (1280x720). The background is added using compositing with nodes. When I render the animation Blender cuts of the edges of my background image so that it fits the animation resolution.

Is there a way to keep the resolution of the background image but render the animation with another resolution and still have the whole background image in the final animation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a Scale node ("Distort -> Scale") to your background image. Then set the space to "Render Size". Then select "Fit".

[image: Scale]